# How to pass downloaded Models from Azure ParallelRunConfig to Entrypoint Script

Tags: python-3.x, azure, parallel-processing, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to perform predictions on a data frame using Azure parallel run step. There are 2 methods to load the models one is to download models in ParallelRunConfig script and pass it to child nodes and the other is to download it on child nodes.

I can use the `environment_variables` parameter in `ParallelRunConfig` to pass the required objects to child nodes but it doesn't support passing .pkl files.

Using the second approach i.e. to download models directly on child nodes is quite expensive and repetitive same model is being downloaded multiple times.

How can I pass pkl files downloaded in ParllelRunConfig Python file to child nodes?

Answer (score 0):

To do this task, you can follow the below steps:

1. Register your pickle model in workspace.
   [image]
2. Use `init()` function in your `entry script` to load the model.
   [image]
3. Use it for processing in the `run(mini_batch)` function.
   [image]

With this I was able to execute the job with `ParallelRunConfig` and `pickle model`.
[image]

Please refer to this [sample notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/parallel-run/tabular-dataset-inference-iris.ipynb) which provide detailed steps on using pickle model with ParallelRunConfig.

**Update:**

Below is the ParallelRunConfig code snippet

```py
from azureml.pipeline.steps import ParallelRunStep, ParallelRunConfig
parallel_run_config = ParallelRunConfig(
    source_directory=scripts_folder,
    entry_script=script_file, 
    mini_batch_size='1KB',
    error_threshold=5,
    output_action='append_row',
    append_row_file_name="iris_outputs.txt",
    environment=predict_env,
    compute_target=compute_target, 
    node_count=2,
    run_invocation_timeout=600
)
```

Details:
[image]
Below is the list of registered models in the workspace.
[image]
With this job executed with prediction from the model
[image]
[image]

Comment: Share the code where you download model in ParallelRunConfig file.

Comment: I have updated the solution with required details.

Comment: How would you pass multiple models? In this scenario you are using only 1 model.

Comment: Also you are downloading the models on child nodes by passing path to the model. Objective is to download models on parent node and pass on to child nodes where they would be loaded only if required. Please keep the code in code blocks instead of images.